# what app/script is responsible for video media?

Tags: video, tasker, media-player, system

When podcast videos or youtube videos or flash videos play, what app is behind that?

I'd like to be able to use that script/app to as a trigger for tasker to do something whenever ANY video is playing.

I don't  want to make the apps a trigger because sometimes when apps like YouTube you are just browsing and not watching any video. I want to make a trigger when the media is actually playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were assuming *State → Hardware → Media Button* coming close to your wishes – but No: That event triggers when [One of the media buttons is pressed](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/sh_index.html), as the name suggests, not when a video/media is played.

When looking for a fitting *Tasker* trigger, the only thing *coming close* to it is checking the `%MTRACK` variable, but that only works for some audio players. To extend that, you can use some *Tasker* addons as e.g. [Wave Control](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Wave-Control/com.MarksThinkTank.WaveControl) or [Media Utilities](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Media-Utilities/com.batescorp.notificationmediacontrols.alpha) – but again, according to their descriptions they seem to work for audio only.

I'm not aware of any possibility to achieve this with *Tasker*; but feel free to check out my [Collection of Tasker Resources](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/435917/), maybe one of the many tutorials mentions anything I overlooked, or one of the addons got updated in this regard.

Comment: Right! Whenever any video or audio is being played, something is connecting its audio to the speakers. There is a global media stream for audio at least and if that could be used as a trigger, that would be awesome. And yes Media Utilities is spotty in its effectiveness.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single app or script that runs for all videos. Some video support is built into the Android framework, and each app also have its own logic for playing videos.

Comment: I noticed in tasker "state -> hardware -> media button" this is probably close to what I'm looking for. Some way to figure our when a video was played.

Comment: After some testing that was a no go either. I guess the best way is to check if youtube is launched in landscape mode. That is generally how i view media. It's disappointing that there isn't a better way to do this.

Comment: @JoshuaRobison I don't know of any OS that has a hook for "anything on the system is playing video". It would require all the apps to co-operate and, if you don't mind me saying, isn't a widespread need.